# multiple actions within short hand javascript

Tags: javascript, shorthand

Hi I am wondering if there is a good way to run multiple functions or methods if a condition is met within short-hand javascript.

I have tried this, but doesn't work:

```
!gameView?launchFull(); alert('action 2'):returnView();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if there is a good way

No.

The ternary operator is a good way to do a simple "If A x = y ELSE x = z". Trying to go beyond that is a good way to create an unreadable mess.

Use a proper `if { } else { }`.

Readability is *far* more valuable then shortness.

Comment: Amen! Being clever = obfuscation.

Comment: I agree. However, it can be useful to remember that if you are only doing one thing each after the IF and ELSE, you can dispense with the brackets. e.g. `if (something) doThis(); else doThat();`

Comment: Dispensing with the braces is a good way to come back to the code 6 months later and add a second statement… and then have everything break. :)

Comment: If you can't notice that there aren't braces when you come back in 6 months, you shouldn't be touching the code in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Can you do it? Yes.
Working example

```
var x = true;
!x?(alert('true 1'),alert('true 2')):(alert('false 1'),alert('false 2'));
```

Note brackets around the sections.

But, should you do it? **no**.

Comment: Sorry I'm 10 years late. Why not ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

> function m() {alert("i am M");}
>
> function k() {alert("i am K");}
>
> function l() {alert("i am L");}
>
> m.call();
>
> var func = 1===1 ? l : k;
>
> func.call();

Func will work as a delegate and when the call is made it will have a function associated with the variable